# Django with react router dont work and show empty page

Tags: reactjs, django

I am using react inside django. I use npx create-react-app and npm run build to create react . The structure looks like this

- frontend
- main
- mysite

In react I have two components. Form and App. App is the one that renders all other components. In settings I have configured frontend/build to be the templates.

main/views.py

```
def createUser(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

main/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
path('register/', views.createUser),
]
```

frontend/src/App.js

```
import Form from './Form';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>  
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/register' element={<Form/>} />
          </Routes>        
</Router>
```

When I go to /register I get a blank page with the css that I wrote for form.js but nothing else shows.